# What is the difference between Timer0 and Timer2 in AVR

Tags: avr, atmega, timer

I'm using ATmega32. This two timers looks very similar. What is a difference between them? When should I use Timer0, and when Timer2?

Comment: Did you read [the datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc2503.pdf)?  There's a separate chapter for each timer.

Comment: Probably one of the two can be routed to the UART peripheral. I didn't check the datasheet, but that is what I remember from a similar search a while ago. There are probably other similar differences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Timer2 is async timer. It means it can count when sleeping. But it's tricky to setup it when external clock is required. When external clock source is to be used a few pulses to setup it correctly is needed. I.e. it limits timer2 counter to be used as random pulse counter.